# aspnetboilerplate core brand new project does not build in vs 2017

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have downloaded asp.net core 2.x angular js template. Opened up with vs 2017 version 15.4.1 and it does not build. When I try to build or restore nuget packages it throws up below error.

The error message :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Assets file '...\3.3.2\aspnet-core\src\MyNg2Project.Core\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. MyNg2Project.Core   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `dotnet restore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had specified local nuget package source to update or restore packages with my team in earlier version of visual studio. Visual studio 2017 assumed that this local path still exist and prioritized it. When I uncheck the old path from the main source of nuget package it worked like a charm.